# Extract thumbnail image urls from a site and print them in jsoup

Tags: jsoup

I want to extract thumbnail image urls from a site and print them in jsoup.
But, I don't understand what exactly has to be selected. This is my code, and this the the content:

Now here, there are three classes. ul,li and img. I've tried selected all of the three but I'm not getting the o/p.

Here's my code:

```
Document doc= Jsoup.connect                                                ("http://www.anthropologie.com/anthro/product/clothes-dress-occasion/4130348694006.jsp#/").get();
 ArrayList<String> im1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        Elements i1 = doc.select(".thumbnail-list");
        String image_url1 = null, src_ends1 = null;

        for (Element er : i1) {


            image_url1 = er.attr("src");
            if (image_url1.endsWith("?$detail-title") || image_url1.endsWith("?$pdp-detail-shot$")) {
                src_ends1 = image_url1.substring(0, image_url1.indexOf("?"));
                String image = src_ends1 + "?$pdp-detail-shot$";
                im1.add(image);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The site uses javascript for loading the thumbnail. This is why you can't get the thumbnail urls.

I suggest you using [ui4j](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j) instead.